# Soundcloud player without flash

Tags: jquery, html, flash, audio, html5-audio

Hi I'm trying to customize an audio player using soundcloud API.
https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/wiki

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reproductor</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="soundcloud/css/sc-player-minimal.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <a href="http://soundcloud.com/dark-pointer/dark-pointer-disconnect-no" class="sc-player">Test</a>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="soundcloud/js/soundcloud.player.api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="soundcloud/js/sc-player.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Only works on Chrome. I think it's because of that I have no flash in firefox. But should play in HTML5 if I have not flash

Does anyone know how to play it with html5?

You can see my tests here: http://jreedon.marcosaguayo.com/

I have tried the examples and not working
http://jreedon.marcosaguayo.com/soundcloud/examples/sc-player-red.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoundCloud uses SoundManager2 to play audio. SoundManager2 will attempt to use native HTML5 audio if the browser can play the mimetype. Firefox 21 *just* added MPEG support (mpeg/mp3/mp4/m4a) for Windows 7 and above. Vista support is due for Firefox 22 and they are also working to possibly add support for XP eventually.

The Linux and Mac versions of Firefox currently do not support MPEG decoding, but they are working hard to do so. The Linux version will likely get support sooner than Mac.

If you are not running Windows 7+ or do not have Firefox 21 installed, then SoundManager2 will see that your browser is unable to play MPEG natively and will automatically fallback to playing the audio with Flash.

Comment: But it doesn't work, I get this error: Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 sc-player.js:151

Comment: Ahh, well I see a few issues with SoundCloud's scripts. First, it's trying to use an old jQuery API `$.browser.msie`, which isn't included in 1.9+. Secondly, they seem to be deciding HTML5/Flash based on whether the browser can play `audio/mpeg` even though it appears that you're trying to play `audio/ogg`. I'd email SoundCloud about this as their scripts seem to be dated and they aren't doing accurate testing for the HTML5/Flash switch.

Comment: Also you aren't declaring the content encoding for your test page. Try including this in your `<head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 1):

Hello my english is very bad but i can give you an answer for you problem because I got the same today and i found a solution pretty ugly but his works. First you must to update flash player on firefox because it doesn't use the audio of html without this the script doesn't work on firefox. And if you want to make a playlist I replace the function api_load with empty function to load a new song.

```
load: function(track) {
          var url = track.uri;
          if(player){
            $('.sc-player-engine-container').empty();
            $('.sc-player-engine-container').append(flashHtml(url));
          }else{
            // create a container for the flash engine (IE needs this to operate properly)
            $('<div class="sc-player-engine-container"></div>').appendTo(document.body).html(flashHtml(url));
          }
        },
```

I can say if this is the good solution because I'm novice on Js and in the web technology also.
See that on my website http://mifatracks.com/